# Rename file on multiple file uploads that issued with underscore

Tags: php, codeigniter

The problem is that when I upload a file it replaces its spaces with underscore.
Because, I get url from ajax so the first string is:

```
$last = $this->uri->total_segments();
    echo $this->uri->segment($last);
```

> EOLU%2012345671545052

With PHP:

```
$id = rawurldecode($this->uri->segment($last));
echo $id;
```

> EOLU 12345671545052

I am uploading multiple files. If 3 files are uploaded I want to give names like this:

```
EOLU 12345671545052 0
EOLU 12345671545052 1
EOLU 12345671545052 2
```

But after looking in my upload directory I saw something like this :

```
EOLU_12345671545052_0
EOLU_12345671545052_1
EOLU_12345671545052_2
```

This is my complete code :

```
$last = $this->uri->total_segments();
$id = rawurldecode($this->uri->segment($last));    
$pathToUpload = './assets/uploads/' . $id;

for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
    $_FILES['file']['name'] = $files['file']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['type'] = $files['file']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] = $files['file']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['error'] = $files['file']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['file']['size'] = $files['file']['size'][$i];

 // we have to initialize before upload

     $config['file_name'] = $id . " ".$i; //Gives name of each file
     echo $config['file_name'];

     $this->upload->initialize($config);
     if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
                $errors++;
     }
  }
```

I tried :

```
$config['file_name'] = str_replace("_", " ", $id) . $i;
```

But it still gives me underscore. Where am I missed? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked the do_upload function?

Comment: Yest, I have.  $this->upload->initialize($config);
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload("file")) {
                    $errors++;
                    echo $this->upload->display_errors();
                }

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$config['remove_spaces'] = false;
```